# done - php sql use callback

Tags: php, sql, callback

EDIT:

PROBLEM IS FOLLOWING:

$pageTitle cannot be used outside the function.

Here is what I got so far:

```
function getMetaData($table, $rows){
    echo $table;
    echo $rows;
    $selectTitle =  "select * from $table";
    $getTitle    = mysql_query($selectTitle);
    while ($showTitle = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTitle)){
        $pageTitle = $showTitle[$rows];
    }
}

getMetaData('metadata', 'Pagetitle');
```

My output

```
<?php echo $pageTitle ?>
```

--> this is undefined

Thank you

Comment: while echoing they are displying correctly..??

Comment: yes that was just for testing

Comment: Does this work: `$pageTitle = $showTitle['Pagetitle'];` inside the while loop?

Comment: your not returning any value

Comment: @DevZer0 could you please explain?

Comment: This question is not clear at all, people are guessing.  Is that a warning?  if it is then the answers from Rohan and Gautam should fix your issue, if not please make your question more clear.

Comment: It is a notice " undefined variable " (this one I am currently echoing in page title --> <?php echo $pageTitle ?>

Comment: @ChristophHa, please post full code and be more descriptive.

Comment: The callback had no relevance in the problem

Comment: why the downvote?
because I did not realize the real problem first?wtf..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not return any value nor does it prints any value. based on your `EDIT` use

```
global $pageTitle;
```

at the beginning of your function and before using the variable.

Comment: how do you expect a callback or what ever it is to work if there is no return value? is there some miracle reflection happening?

Comment: I guess everyone here is playing a guessing game.  Now after OP's comment, you could be the winner.  Let's wait for OP's code.

Comment: I got not a callback but a scope problem I noticed, think I will solve this now ..

Comment: yes that was right! 
coming from javascript I forgot about this stuff
thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just TRY with `mysql_free_result()` like

```
$selectTitle =  "SELECT * FROM '".$table."'";
$getTitle    = mysql_query($selectTitle);
$pageTitle = '';
while ($showTitle = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTitle)){
    $pageTitle = $showTitle[$rows];
}
return $pageTitle;               //Return even the pageTitle.
```

`mysql_free_result()` will free all memory associated with the result.

And as per your EDIT try like :

```
$pageTitle = getMetaData('metadata', 'Pagetitle');
echo $pageTitle;
```

Comment: @ChristophHa, what are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the `variable $pageTitle` first like,

```
function getMetaData($table, $rows){
    echo $table;
    echo $rows;
    $selectTitle =  "select * from $table";
    $getTitle    = mysql_query($selectTitle);
    $pageTitle='';
    while ($showTitle = mysql_fetch_assoc($getTitle)){
        $pageTitle = $showTitle[$rows];
    }
    return $pageTitle; // returning the variable will work here
}
echo getMetaData('metadata', 'Pagetitle');
```

Comment: does not work either ;)
without callback it works fine, so I think it is not because of initializing the variable

Comment: The above will work properly, you need to check in your `database table`. Do you have any data in your `database table` or not, also you need to use `LIMIT` here.